# Что за амперсанд в конструкторе класса (&) с c++?

Tags: c++, hook

```
class MyHook{
public:
    
    static MyHook& Instance(){
        static MyHook myHook;
        return myHook;
    }   
    HHOOK hook; 
    void InstallHook(); 
    void UninstallHook();
    MSG msg; 
    int Messsages(); 
};
LRESULT WINAPI MyMouseCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam); //callback declaration
```

Я не понимаю что это за синтаксис такой :

```
static MyHook& Instance(){
        static MyHook myHook;
        return myHook;
    }
```

Что значит статический конструктор,и зачем этот амперсанд '&',почему в конструкторе создается опять класс и куда он возвращается?...

Comment: Почему вы вообще думаете, что это конструктор. Это функция (статическая), возвращающая `MyHook &` (ссылку на `MyHook`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Познакомьтесь с классическим [синглтоном Майерса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#C++).

Эта штука работает так - при первом обращении к `static MyHook& Instance()` будет создан синглтон. При этом, `C++11` дополнительно гарантирует, что это будет сделано потокобезопасным образом.

Все последующие вызовы метода будут возвращать ранее созданный объект.

Для полной классичности, не хватает удаления конструктора копирования, конструктора присваивания, а также прикрытия обычного конструктора в `private`

Тогда класс невозможно будет ни создать, ни скопировать, что и будет гарантировать существование единственного экземпляра этого класса в программе.